# Log rotation not happening with cron job- files are symlinked and forceful log rotation works

Tags: cron, logrotate

I am facing issue with logrotation with 2 of my custom files. The folder where they reside - `/var/log/test` is symlinked to `/sample/var/log/test`

cron.daily log which picks up logrotate:

```
Sep 12 03:20:01 xxx anacron[]: Job `cron.daily' started
Sep 12 03:20:01 xxx run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[]: starting logrotate
Sep 12 03:20:01 xxx run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[]: finished logrotate
```

But logrotate status never updates the file times (this time was when I did the logrotation forcefully using `-f`):

**`cat /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status`**

```
"/var/log/test/xxxx.out" 2018-9-10-14:14:49
"/var/log/test/yyyy.out" 2018-9-10-14:14:49
```

This is my logrotation configuration:

**`cat /etc/logrotate.d/test`**

```
/var/log/test/xxxx.out
/var/log/test/yyyy.out {
        missingok
        notifempty
        rotate 7
        copytruncate
        compress
        daily
        create 0644 root root
}
```

It rotates the file when I do:
**`logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/test`**

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

logrotate.d is configuration structure, I.E. not the actual configuration. The files in `logrotate.d` still need to be referenced by `logrotate.conf`.

This line looks like `include /etc/logrotate.d/*.conf` or similar. So if you add the appropriate extension to your file it will probably be included. See the [logrotate man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for more information.

Comment: Hi Alex - It does have include /etc/logrotate.d in the logrotate.conf. All other files in the logrotate.d are taken up in cron job.

Comment: Have you tried naming the file something other than `test`? Also, what is the configured value in logrotate.conf of `tabooext`?

Comment: Ok i will try renaming my file and check out. Also, I dont see anything as tabooext value in the conf file, where do i check that?

Comment: It's in the man page I linked above. Just wondered if "test" was a "taboo extension" that it was ignoring.

Comment: I tried renaming it and still the log rotation doesnt happen.